# parsing json data in for loop statement using swift 2

Tags: ios, json, swift, for-loop, swift2

I am developing a app using swift2 am parsing JSON data to a `UITableView` which works perfectly when click on the cell it moves to other view controller and fetching some data to label box. The problem is when I clicks any cells on the table view it fetching same data to a view controller I dont know how to parse the data into for loop statement.

Json data(data am recieving from the server):

```
{
  item: [
   {
     name: "name1",
     id: "1",
   },
   {
     name: "name2",
     id: "2"
   }
  ]
}
```

Code what I have tried:

created outlet labelname and labelid

```
var arrDict :NSMutableArray=[]
let urlstring = "www.anything.com"
let url = NSURL(string: urlString) 
let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: [])
let json = JSON(data: data)
print(json)

//it helps to print all the json data in console
```

Now help me work with forloop statement

Comment: Your JSON as printed is invalid.

Comment: that is duplicate one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,it helps you:-

```
 for (_, subjson): (String, JSON) in json["item"]{

     print("YOUR SUBJSON VALUE>> \(subjson["name"].stringValue)")
                    }
```

Comment: while am printing in console it executes well but parsing same data to label box...because in func did select row at index path i just connected to other view controller.in other view controller am having four label box i have to parse data into that

Comment: can you provide any example to work with func did select row at index path

Comment: You can pass the "subjson" to that viewController and parse it again as mentioned above the code i.e subjson["name"].stringValue)"

Comment: how do i give reference to that view controller....because all functions are written in table view controller..only label outlet is provided in view controller...

Comment: create a refernce to ViewController2 :- var objSubjson:JSON!
and in viewController1:-

'let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController1") as! viewController1
            vc.objSubjson = subjson
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)'

Answer (score 0):

```
var listArray = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
listArray["name"] =  json["item"]?.valueForKey("name") as! Array
listArray["id"]  = json["item"]?.valueForKey("id") as! Array

var name = [""]
var id = [""]

name = listArray["name"] as! Array
id = listArray["id"] as! Array

for i in 0..<name.count{
  print(name[i])
  print(id[i])
}
hope it will help
```

Comment: i will follow your method and reply back....thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 let array = json["item"] as! [NSDictionary]
 for dict in array {
    let name = dict["name"] as! String
    let id = dict["id"] as! String
 }
```

i hope this will help you

Comment: yeah sure..i will check and reply..thank you for your answer

Comment: It gives me warning as: cast from json to unrelated type nsdictionary always fails

Comment: put this let dataDict = json as! NSDictionary

Comment: if you out put of  "print(json)" is same as above then it should be work.
Check my updated Answer

Comment: sorry you need to remove 
let dataDict = json as? NSDictionary if you are using swifty json

Answer (score -1):

take all json data in an NSArray(if data is in Array)

like this:

let arr = json as!  NSArray

for i in 0...arr.count-1

{

let items = arr[i] as! NSMutableDictionary

var abc = items.valueForKey("name"))as! String
//Like this you can take all array values

}

hope it will help you.